# Reference library targeting .NET Standard from a Windows Store app or Profile7 PCL?

Tags: windows-store-apps, portable-class-library, .net-standard

The [doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) says a library targeting .NET Standard can reference a "profile-based PCL".  But what about the reverse?  Can a `Profile 7` PCL reference a library targeting .NET Standard (any version)?

Also, can a Windows Store (Windows 8.1) app reference a library that only targets .NET Standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a Profile 7 PCL reference a library targeting .NET Standard (any
>   version)?

You may refer to [this article](https://xamarinhelp.com/dot-net-standard-pcl-xamarin-forms/) written by @Adam Pedly Microsoft MVP (Xamarin):

" ***Remember that once you have a .NET Standard Library a Profile Based PCL can’t reference it, hence you need to convert everything up the chain to .NET Standard***."

**Update**:

Check the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library#net-platforms-support), see the complete set of .NET runtimes that support the .NET Standard Library. So if you want to reference it in Windows 8.1 project, you can target .NET Standard 1.2, which provides less functions than .NET Standard 1.6 version(e.g. no `System.Net.Sockets`).

Comment: What .NET Standard version does the Windows 8.1 app support?  I am unable to add a reference to [Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch/).  And where does Microsoft document this?

Comment: I think `Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch` targets .NET Standard 1.3.

Comment: Sorry for my misleading. I just check the URL you provide. Yes, it indeed targets .NET Standard 1.3. The Windows 8.1 project should support .NET Standard 1.2. You might check the table in the doc at my update answer.